# Understanding asp.net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So recently I've been given the opportunity to take on an ongoing project. The project has been coded in c# using the asp.net MVC framework (and Microsoft SQL as the database). I've never used any of these tools and my web development knowledge is mostly based on WAMP/LAMP. I want to develop the web app locally, so firstly, how exactly do I serve the content on my local computer? It doesn't seem to be as simple as installing WAMP and moving files into a /www/ directory, and then going to the localhost address.

If someone could point me in the right direction in setting up the development environment, that would also be really helpful. I already have visual studio 2012 ultimate installed (which is also new to me, I've only used eclipse in the past).

Also, should I go ahead and download the 180 day microsoft sql server evaluation? I've also heard of something called localDB, how do these compare? Is it an easy transfer between the two?

Thanks!

Comment: I woulf suggest looking at the MSDN based tutorials first.

Comment: Start from here - http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: Check this: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp.nt+learn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Zg3&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1&q=asp.net+learn&sa=X&ei=YgLYUPacC4GSrgfa3YGQCQ&ved=0CDMQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk&fp=763f662d365af90a&bpcl=40096503&biw=1600&bih=772

Answer (score 3):

When you are using Visual Studio you do not need to move files to an directory like a /www/, just press the run button saying the name of the default browser. This starts the IIS server with your project loaded. Closing the debug mode will not close the server, and you can make changes to the project without clicking the start button again. Just note that the C# files need to be compiled(the build option) and .chtml files do not.

LocalDb is the default database in new MVC projects. It is more geared towards developers. I am not sure how big your project is and what kind of management is required, so I cannot say what is better suited. But for development for on an local machine LocalDb should suffice. See [Introducing LocalDB, an improved SQL Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) and the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655374/sql-localdb-vs-sql-server-ce) for more information.

I recommend going to [MVC Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for the basics, especially [ASP.NET MVC Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview). On the right are a bunch of videos that I highly recommend watching, they helped me out a lot when I first started with MVC. [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/asp.net+mvc) Also have useful videos about Visual Studio and ASP.NET MVC.

I hope I this will put you on the right track and good luck.