# SQL Server LocalDB or SQL Server Compact

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out whether I can user SQL Server LocalDB instead of SQL Server Compact.

I'm in process of developing software (.Net Framework 4.5 + Entity Framework 5) that needs to use local DB (like SQLite or SQL Server Compact). But of course I've paid an attention to new feature (LocalDB) of SQL Server 2012 Express. In the official documents is said that LocalDB is mostly used by developers if they don't want to maintain the full instance of SQL Server Express.

For me it's not a problem to install 33 Mb version of LocalDB on production computers. So what will be the better choice to me? To use LocalDB or Compact?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc hope it helps

Comment: Look at the first answer to [SQL LocalDB vs SQL Server CE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9655578/1175077)