# Free small database for small apps that works on both 32bit and 64bit Windows?

Tags: .net, database, relational-database

do you know any free small database for small apps that works on both 32bit and 64bit Windows ?

Should i try SQLLite or something like that ?

What do you recommend ?

Thanks !

Comment: SQLite is good, there is also XML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last solution from Microsoft is SQL Server Compact 4.0:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876
It is totally free.

I would recommend to used it instead of other 3rd party solution because it seamless integration with LINQ and EntityFramework.

Moreover, you can have in the future a dual application supporting local and server-based database with minimal configuration.

Another advantage is that you can use ClickOnce to deploy it along with your application.

Answer (score 0):

I answered something similar here, but it doesn't detail 32/64bit support:

[What is a good choice of database for a small .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749556/what-is-a-good-choice-of-database-for-a-small-net-application/6749583#6749583)

However, lots of the popular ones offer this support.

I know SQL CE has 64-bit libraries, so this is a viable solution. I am currently using this with NHibernate in a small .NET app without any issue.