# What c# tool do i have to manage small database?

Tags: c#, database

I need a tool that will allow the user to create small databases(lookup tables, formulas, constants)
and extract information from them later.
the information(value's) i get from the database will be inserted to an xml file i need for my work.
the size of the database will be small but its not known to me now so i need a way
for the user to enter it.
what simple tool do i have in c# to do that?

Comment: Maybe the in-memory [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=vs.110).aspx) or do you need to store the data physically?

Comment: I've got a list of small databases for .NET [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749556/what-is-a-good-choice-of-database-for-a-small-net-application/6749583#6749583), it has one or two links for management tools.

Comment: Tim i need to store the data for future use.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).
SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world.

Comment: Keep in mind that SQLite only supports a subset of SQL queries and datatypes, but is a very good start if you want to store data physically.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database.. perhaps something like [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) or for the embedded kind perhaps [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). NoSQL might be useful for you if you're unsure what structure your users' data may take.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd like to have some kind of Database Manager?
If you do so then it depends on the database system.

For example if you would like to manage MySQL databases you should have a look at the [.Net Connector for MySQL databases](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
As far as I know there is a support for SQLite in .Net so you wouldn't need any external libs for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SqlServerCe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134.aspx). It is an In-App database which can be accessed only from one application at a time.