# Sqlite in C# with REGEXP

Tags: c#, regex, sqlite

I'm trying to build a search query to match whole words in SQLite and C# on Windows. When I run a query like this:

```
SELECT a, b FROM Events WHERE c REGEXP @SearchString;
```

Then:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@SearchString", 
"%[^a-zA-Z0-9]" + searchdata.SearchText + "[^a-zA-Z0-9]%"));
```

And when I call:

```
var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I get REGEXP no such function. I wonder how to activate REGEXP support and CASE SENSITIVE search.

Comment: Did you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query) and the answer from mivk?

Comment: Yes, but I'm on Windows and I cannot find a link to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got it! The problem was that I didn't define the REGEXP function. I've got from here:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172735/create-use-user-defined-functions-in-system-data-sqlite) a definition for C#.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `%`. That is only for `LIKE`.

Comment: The same error. The problem is the REGEXP not the parameter format. I think Konrad is correct to point me that something is missing but what?

Comment: @PabloYabo what version of sqlite are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQLite.NET 1.0.88.0 - August 7, 2013. SQLite 3.7.17

Comment: @PabloYabo ensure that it is in your build of sqlite.

Comment: How I should do that?