# How do I UnitTest with In Memory DB a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I am using SQLite InMemory DB to test my app, with Entity Framework Core and when I execute some queries like (`select * from Users`).

But when I try to do a stored procedure call `dbo.GET_ALL_USERS`", it fails because SQLite doesn't support stored procedures...

So, how do you test an app that uses stored procedures?

Can I convert the stored procedure to multiple queries?

Can I mock the result of the stored procedure?

Comment: You don't do it that way. You'll need to mock the call

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172735/create-use-user-defined-functions-in-system-data-sqlite

Comment: If I mock the call then I have to do more work, mocking all the news call and agregate that to the unitests...

Answer (score 0):

I use tSQLt for unit testing my stored procedures in SQL Server
https://tsqlt.org/

For MySQL, I use http://utmysql.sourceforge.net/